# How do I fix permission denied error after upgrading dependencies?

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-install, package.json, permission-denied

I am facing the following issue. Any help is highly appreciated.

I am upgrading one dependency in my project as per *White-source* advice: `normalize-url`, from the version 4.5.0 to 4.5.1 in order to fix security vulnerabilities.

The application runs fine and I have to test a `search` call which gets a 200 code and shows a response of a JSON found in `"/initial-db.json"`.

But, After I just run `npm install normalize-url@latest` I can see the version in the package-lock.json is getting upgraded, but when I test my application, the search call gets a 500 code with the following error:

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/prod/msp/apps/src/data/initial-db.json'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:476:3)
    at writeFileSync (fs.js:1467:35)
    at FileSync.write (/prod/msp/apps/node_modules/lowdb/adapters/FileSync.js:53:14)
    at LodashWrapper.db.write (/prod/msp/apps/node_modules/lowdb/lib/main.js:37:21)
    at /prod/msp/apps/node_modules/json-server/lib/server/router/write.js:5:8
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/prod/msp/apps/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/prod/msp/apps/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at create (/prod/msp/apps/node_modules/json-server/lib/server/router/singular.js:37:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/prod/msp/apps/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/prod/msp/apps/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
```

I also tried to run `npm update normalize-url --depth 7` as I saw in some suggested answers and I get the same behaviour.
I also ran `npm ls normalize-url` and then I updated the all the dependencies in the tree, but still with the same results.

Any idea could help. :)

Comment: At a guess, I'd say it looks like a weird file permissions problem that isn't specifically about npm. I'd try deleting `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` to start fresh, and see if that helps.

Comment: @kshetline thank you for the quick reply.
 I deleted both `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and rerun `npm install` and `npm install normalize-url@latest` and I still got the same problem.